# ArcGIS JS, extent on service (raster)

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm creating a layer from service with `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer`

```
layerServicios = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(service_url, {
    id: id_layer,
    opacity: 0.9,
    imageParameters: imageParams
});
console.log('layerServicios', layerServicios):

{
attributionDataUrl: ""
capabilities: "Map,Query,Data"
className: undefined
copyright: ""
credential: undefined
description: ""
dpi: 96
fullExtent: {type: "extent", xmin: -113.99999550732358, ymin: -62.566660275992355, xmax: -58.9560316118582, ymax: -14.26532106013001, …}
gdbVersion: undefined
getImageUrl: ƒ ()
hasAttributionData: false
id: "layer_mapas_3"
imageFormat: "png8"
imageTransparency: true
infoTemplates: null
initialExtent: {type: "extent", xmin: -70.34055967658617, ymin: -33.83365057356685, xmax: -70.31957965174547, ymax: -33.605022097738875, …}
isPNG32: undefined
layerDefinitions: []
layerInfos: (305) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
loaded: true
maxImageHeight: 4096
maxImageWidth: 4096
maxRecordCount: 1000000000
maxScale: 0
minScale: 0
normalization: true
onError: ƒ ()
onLoad: ƒ ()
onOpacityChange: ƒ ()
etc...
}
```

When I was working with graphic layer, I had no problem on zoom to extent with:

```
var gLayer = map.getLayer(id_layer);
var ge = GraphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(gLayer.graphics);
map.setExtent(ge, true);
```

But now I don't know how to setExtent in this case, with a service thar returns a raster

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `fullExtent` property of your [`ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html)

```
map.setExtent(rasterLayer.fullExtent);
```